# Requirements.txt not installing only "requests" package in Azure App

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, requirements.txt

I am trying to host webapp on azure. I have requirements.txt file with different packages. But I find that webapp backend container is not installing only 1 package-  "requests". All other packages with dependencies are installed. The webapp uses python 2.7.9 version on linux.

Below is my requirements.txt file

```
requests==2.25.0
Flask==1.1.1
```

any pointers much appreciated

Comment: Are you running this command exact;y? ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` because it works fine for me

Comment: Manually it works, but azure app installs it automatically. Problem is if I access the container and manually install, it does not affect the app because it is still running. When I reset the app, the package are again reinstalled without "requests"

Comment: After reading the comments above, it is recommended to try another `2.24.0` version, at least it can be ruled out whether it is because the version is not compatible with azure webapp.

Comment: @user437777 did you find any solution for this?